# File `multirow.sty' not found. TexStudio Fedora 29

Tags: packages, multirow, ctan, linuxfedora

I use TexStudio in Fedora 29 and try to execute this bit of code:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{Multiple row} & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
& cell5 & cell6 \\ 
& cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

which requires `\usepackage{multirow}`.

I have downloaded the multirow package from https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow and manually installed the package like many times before with other missing packages (tabu, yax etc.).

I `sudo texhash` and compile but I still get the error message:

> `File multirow.sty not found'

When I look inside the package which I have downloaded from CTAN indeed there is no `multirow.sty` file in the bundle so why but why TexStudio is asking for it?

Comment: Don't install packages manually. That is the job of the past!

Comment: Here is [how to install a full TeX Live for Fedore 25](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/105940/how-to-install-full-version-of-texlive-in-fedora-25-from-command-line/). The answer is quite old (Fedore 25 not 29) but AFAIK should still be valid. The full installation should contain `multirow`. As an alternative you *could* install [Vanilla TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive). But this should not be necessary.

Comment: It is very common for Linux distributions to split TeXLive into smaller Linux packages (not to be confused with LaTeX packages), lets all them bundles. Thus when you ask your Linux distribution to install texlive, chances are that you just get some default collection of texlive related bundles. But it does not include everything. This confuses a **LOT** of Linux users. On Ubuntu we have the `texlive-full` pseudo bundle, which installs all texlive related bundles at once. You probably have something similar on Fedora.

Comment: @daleif Yes there is something similar on Fedore. See the first link in my first comment …

Comment: `sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full` from (https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/105940/how-to-install-full-version-of-texlive-in-fedora-25-from-command-line/) is what I did. it took time but this particular problems seems solved. thank you good people!

Comment: btw: I installed my TexStudio from Software directly. I did not expect all this trouble with an official repository...

Comment: Texstudio is only the editor. But because it is a LaTeX editor Fedora automatically installs a more or less minimal TeX Live with LaTeX too. This is a common problem of new LaTeX users.

Comment: This is also why a lot of "heavy" LaTeX users on Linux, tend to use the _upstream_ TeXLive instead of the TeXLive from the linux dist. This also have a tendency to be more up to date. If you are a "normal" users, who does not rely on cutting edge packages, then just use the TeXLive from the linux dist.